# Looking for update for number of days using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table t1 with below table structure:

```
Period_xi yearmonth
1          2021/01
2          2021/02
```

period_Xi is the primary key of table t1. I am going to create 2nd table t2 as below:

```
period_xi yearmonth  CM-1   CM-2 CM-3 CM-4 CM-5 CM-6 CM-7 CM-8 CM-9 CM-10 CM-11 CM-2
1          2021/01    31    30    31   
2          2021/02
```

I have to update the column CM-1 as 31, CM-2 as 30 days to find out the number of days for previous month.

trying to find update SQL to update last 12 months (number of days) in single SQL

Is it possible to do this

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Please [edit] your post so that the title is more descriptive of the problem you're having or the question you're asking. "SQL" and "Oracle" are both available in the tags, so they're not needed in the title. Removing them leaves "update", which has no meaning and conveys no information. While you're editing, you can include your attempts to do this yourself (your SQL). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query to find the previous twelve months based on the date represented by `yearmonth`; this finds the last three months for brevity:

```
select period_xi, yearmonth, level as offset,
  extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -level))) as days
from t1
connect by level <= 3
and prior period_xi = period_xi
and prior dbms_random.value is not null;

PERIOD_XI YEARMONTH OFFSET DAYS
--------- --------- ------ ----
        1 2021/01        1   31
        1 2021/01        2   30
        1 2021/01        3   31
        2 2021/02        1   31
        2 2021/02        2   31
        2 2021/02        3   30
...
```

You can then pivot the result into multiple columns (assuming you are on 11g or later):

```
select * from (
  select period_xi, yearmonth, level as offset,
    extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -level))) as days
  from t1
  connect by level <= 12
  and prior period_xi = period_xi
  and prior dbms_random.value is not null
)
pivot (max(days) for (offset) in (1 as "CM-01", 2 as "CM-02", 3 as "CM-03",
  4 as "CM-04", 5 as "CM-05", 6 as "CM-06", 7 as "CM-07", 8 as "CM-08",
  9 as "CM-09", 10 as "CM-10", 11 as "CM-11", 12 as "CM-12"));

PERIOD_XI YEARMONTH CM-01 CM-02 CM-03 CM-04 CM-05 CM-06 CM-07 CM-08 CM-09 CM-10 CM-11 CM-12
--------- --------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
        2 2021/02      31    31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31    29
        1 2021/01      31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31    29    31
        3 2021/03      28    31    31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31
...
```

You could use that to insert into your new table, or as part of an update or merge. It might be simpler to create a view form it though, rather than store duplicate data.

You could also use virtual columns, again from 11g:

```
create table t2 (period_xi number, yearmonth varchar2(7),
  cm_01 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -1)))),
  cm_02 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -2)))),
  cm_03 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -3)))),
  cm_04 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -4)))),
  cm_05 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -5)))),
  cm_06 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -6)))),
  cm_07 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -7)))),
  cm_08 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -8)))),
  cm_09 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -9)))),
  cm_10 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -10)))),
  cm_11 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -11)))),
  cm_12 number generated always as (extract(day from last_day(add_months(to_date(yearmonth, 'YYYY/MM/'), -12))))
);

insert into t2 (period_xi, yearmonth) values (1, '2021/01');
insert into t2 (period_xi, yearmonth) values (2, '2021/02');
insert into t2 (period_xi, yearmonth) values (3, '2021/03');

select * from t2;

PERIOD_XI YEARMONTH CM_01 CM_02 CM_03 CM_04 CM_05 CM_06 CM_07 CM_08 CM_09 CM_10 CM_11 CM_12
--------- --------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
        1 2021/01      31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31    29    31
        2 2021/02      31    31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31    29
        3 2021/03      28    31    31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for sharing detailed answer. Yes my oracle db is 11g. i will definitely test and reply soon.